# Why do we use nullable string in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In Microsoft official Learning Module "Create a Web API with ASP.NET Core" Why some sample codes use nullable string type although we know strings are nullable in itself since it is a reference type?
See Model/Pizza.cs class in this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/build-web-api-aspnet-core/5-exercise-add-data-store).

Comment: I think it's so that you can effectively flag where something could be null (absence of data) and therefore requires null checks vs something that can't be null. More info: https://www.focisolutions.com/2021/04/nullable-reference-types-in-c-8-0/#:~:text=Nullable%20reference%20types%20are%20a,Value%20and%20Nullability%20Analysis%20checks.

Comment: It's called ["Nullable Reference Type"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) aka NRT. Relatively new feature of C# helping devs to know when something can be null or it's guarantied no never be null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C# 8.0, a new language feature was introduced for [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) which was intended to help remove the whole class of problems around accidentally dereferencing `null` objects.

By assuming that all reference types are not actually nullable, the compiler can flag up suspicious code based on its own analysis of how `null` values may propagate through the code.

The `?` annotations you see in the tutorial are indications of what fields/properties etc. are allowed to contain `null` and therefore need to be checked as such before doing anything with them.